# Can anyone translate the air traffic vocabulary in Five Miles Out by Mike Oldfield?

Tags: mike-oldfield

In the song [Five Miles Out by Mike Oldfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Miles_Out_(song)) he employs some air traffic control vocabulary as follows:

> What do you do when you're falling,
> You've got 30 degrees and you're stalling out?
> And it's 24 miles to your beacon;
> There's a crack in the sky and the warning's out.
> Don't take that dive again!
> Push through that band of rain!
> Five miles out,
> Just hold your heading true.
> Got to get your finest out.
> You're Number 1, anticipating you.
> Climbing out.
> Just hold your heading true.
> Got to get your finest out.
> You're Number 1, anticipating you.
> Mayday! Mayday! Mayday!
> Calling all stations!
> **This is Golf-Mike-Oscar-Victor-Juliet**
> **IMC CU.NIMB...icing**,
> In great difficulty, over.
> The traffic controller is calling,
> **"Victor-Juliet, your identity.**
> I have you lost in the violent storm!
> Communicate or **squawk 'Emergency'!"**
> Don't take that dive again!
> Push through that band of rain!
> **Lost in static, 18,**
> And the storm is closing in now.
> **Automatic, 18!**
> etc...

[Full lyrics here](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tudpoiaoksq43bzaykc6g56stjm?lyrics=1)

I've highlighted the bits I don't understand, can anyone provide a translation ?

Comment: "30 degrees and stalling out" isn't highlighted, but I suspect you didn't get that one either.     "30°" is not temperature, but the extension of the wing flaps, which are used to increase the lift provided by the wings.  When there isn't sufficient lift, the plane is no longer flying and will drop straight down (known as "stalling").  — Also, "Victor-Juliet" is simply the nickname for "GMOVJ", which is used when there is no other aircraft in the area with the same two last letters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can get you started, but I don't know it all...

Golf Mike Oscar Victoria Juliet is the plane's [registration 'plate'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_registration) which is what a pilot will use to identify his craft to Air Traffic Control.
G-MOVJ

G is the prefix for the United Kingdom.

The letters are spelled out using the [international spelling alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_alphabet), which is used to avoid any confusion. English is the language used by all pilots & ATCs worldwide.

*Wow!* I found the rest via Google...

> [The radio message](http://www.ommadawn.dk/design1.php?sideid=207)
>
> - Mayday
>     The pilots' version of SOS, repeated three times to indicate the beginning of an urgent emergency message.
> - Calling all stations ...
>     not only one because he's really in trouble.
> - Golf Mike Oscar Victor Juliet
>     This spells out GMOVJ, which is kind of the plane's licence number. Look at the painting on the album, you
>     can actually see the letters on the plane. This is a callsign asigned
>     to Scotland (The two first letters (GM) say that). Radio Callsigns
>     prefix are internationally stablished and assigned each one to one
>     country.
> - IMC
>     "Instrument Meteorological Conditions", meaning that the weather is so bad that he can't see anything and has to fly by
>     instruments only. This is because he's flying through:
> - cu nimb
>     which means "cumulonimbus" which are bad-weather clouds, bringing lots of turbulence, rain, hail, and:
> - icing
>     Ice is getting on the wings and propeller blades of the plane, which is extremely dangerous because it will disturb their
>     aerodynamic shape. With enough icing, the plane is sure to go down.
> - Over
>     Terminates the radio message.

-

> [Squawk emergency](http://www.ommadawn.dk/design1.php?sideid=208)
>
> "Squawk".
>   Airplanes are required nowadays to carry a small radio
>   transmitter which transmits a small amount of airplane information to
>   control towers and such so that they can identify those strange blips
>   on their radar screens. When they "squawk", they send this information
>   out. I guess "Squawk emergency" means to send this information on a
>   special emergency band. (This spurred a comment.) This is basically
>   correct, with the following data: The "transmitter" is a RADAR
>   transponder. This is a device that only transmits when it receives a
>   request to do so (it "Transmits a Response", hence "TranSponder").
>
> The Controller on the ground identifies an aircraft by observing
>   specific codes that are displayed along with the RADAR image. Now,
>   it's computerised, but when I was familliar with this system, we used
>   to have to decode little lines next to the RADAR image!
>
> An aircraft will have four dials, 0 to 7 on each dial. The controller
>   tells the plane what code to "squawk" so that they can be identified.
>   This is dialed into the transponder by means of the wheels, usually
>   something like "1212". When the RADAR sweeps the aircraft, the
>   transponder sends out the dialed-in code and the RADAR computer
>   identifies the aircraft on the controller's screen.
>
> 7700 is the EMERGENCY code number! This lights up RADAR screens all
>   over! When an aircraft sets this code, people pay attention!

& the last is a quote from Mike Oldfield himself...

> [Lost in static 18](http://www.ommadawn.dk/design1.php?sideid=209)
>
> "If you look at the cover of Five Miles Out, the
>   plane is a Beech 18. If your radio is breaking up, the control tower
>   would tell you "Lost in static" and then give the call-sign, so it was
>   "Lost in static, 18". It was just one of the lyrics I scribbled down
>   one evening in the pub! When I was writing that song I just scribbled
>   down anything I could think of to do with aeroplanes, and then
>   assembled them into lyrics."